# How to dynamically modify the value in the annotation object on the method, when spring starts and initializes the bean

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, annotations

For example:

```
@RabbitHandler
    @RabbitListener(bindings = @QueueBinding(
            value = @Queue(value = RabbitMqConstant.QUEUE_MESSAGE_NOTIFICATION_ANDROID_PUSHED, durable = "true", autoDelete = "false"),
            exchange = @Exchange(value = RabbitMqConstant.EXCHANGE_DIRECT_NOTIFICATION_ANDROID, type = ExchangeTypes.DIRECT)), ackMode = "MANUAL")
    public void androidPushByAccount(NotificationDto notificationDto, @Header(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG) long deliveryTag, Channel channel) throws Exception {

}
```

I want to add arguments to consumer listeners in batches, like this:

```
  arguments = {
                                            @Argument(name = "x-dead-letter-exchange", value = RabbitConfig.DEAD_DIRECT_EXCHANGE),
                                            @Argument(name = "x-dead-letter-routing-key", value = RabbitConfig.DEAD_LETTER_ROUTING_KEY),
                                            @Argument(name = "x-max-length", value = RabbitConfig.MAX_LENGTH, type = "java.lang.Integer"),
                                            @Argument(name = "x-message-ttl", value = RabbitConfig.MESSAGE_TTL, type = "java.lang.Integer")
                                    }
```

I created RabbitListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor like  this:

```
@Component
public class TbtRabbitListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {
    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {

        Class<?> targetClass = AopUtils.getTargetClass(bean);
        Collection<RabbitListener> classLevelListeners = findListenerAnnotations(targetClass);
        classLevelListeners.forEach(rabbitListener -> {

          for(QueueBinding queueBinding: rabbitListener.bindings())  {
   
               //how to  modify  arguments value ?????
                queueBinding.value().arguments()
          }
        });
         
        return BeanPostProcessor.super.postProcessBeforeInitialization(bean, beanName);
    }
}
```

How to  modify  arguments value  in  method postProcessBeforeInitialization?

Comment: You don't. They are part of the class metadata and cannot be changed. Why do you need to modify them in the first place?